# Appending an empty array with vectors

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to append an empty array with vectors. Yet, no matter what command I use the result is not what I wanted because the result is a vector, and I wanted an array. Here is the sample of my code (s is an array of binary data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s=pd.read_csv('dane1.txt', header=None)
a=s.columns
a=len(a)
b=len(s)
Xi0=[]
i=0

for j in range (b):
    if (s[i][j]==0):
        z=[]
        for k in range(a):
            z.append(s[k][j])
        Xi0=np.append(Xi0,z,axis=0)
```

In other words I want an array made of z vectors in that manner:

```
[z
z
z] etc
```

and I am getting [z z z]
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is  the variable `s`

Comment: It is an array looking exactly like this
https://www.ii.pwr.edu.pl/~drwal/docs/dane1.txt

Comment: And `b`, and `a`

Comment: a - number of columns, b - number of rows

Comment: @Hawkeye - Do you need `Xi0 = s.values[s.values[:, 0] == 0]` ? I think in numpy is the best avoid loops.

Comment: Well, yep, that helped me, thank you!

Comment: `np.append` bites again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need boolean indexing only:

```
arr = s.values
Xi0 = arr[arr[:, 0] == 0]
 print (Xi0)
[[0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think your desired output is an array containing the rows of `s` that start with zero. If that's true, just use `numpy`:

```
result = s.values[s.values[:, 0] == 0]
result
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```